# PHP - explode or preg_split to arrange an array

Tags: php, regex

i have some problems with an array

I have a .txt file that i'm adding into a php file with

```
$file = file_get_contents('data.txt');
```

data.txt contains a list in this format:

```
<info1 info2 0.10s [info: info] 10.10.10.10:80>
<info1 info2 0.10s [info: info, info] 10.10.10.10:80>
<info1 info2 0.10s [info:80, info:25] 10.10.10.10:80>
<info1 info2 0.10s [info: info, info, info:80, info:25] 10.10.10.10:80>
and so on
```

Then I'm using:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $file);
```

Instead of using explode and file_get_contents i can use

```
$lines = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
```

if i do:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($lines);
echo '</pre>';
```

I get this array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
    [3] => 
    ....
)
```

I'm trying very hard to get the array to look like this so i can foreach and display the info or to add it into database

```
Array 
(

info1
info2
time
info *whats inside the []
ip

)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for looking into this !

---

for start I'm struggling to get a foreach to work

```
foreach($lines as $line => $data)
{
$lines_data = explode(' ', $data); //here i've tried to use preg_split with regex and i'm unable to get it to work

$info[$line]['info1'] = $lines_data[0];
$info[$line]['info2'] = $lines_data[1];
$info[$line]['time'] = $lines_data[2];
$info[$line]['info'] = $lines_data[3];
$info[$line]['ip'] = $lines_data[4];

echo ' info1: ' . $info[$line]['info1'] . '<br />';
echo ' info2: ' . $info[$line]['info2'] . '<br />';
echo ' time: ' . $info[$line]['time'] . '<br />';
echo ' info: ' . $info[$line]['info'] . '<br />';
echo ' ip: ' . $info[$line]['ip'] . '<br />';
}
```

it's not working in this way cause ***explode(' ', $data);*** is splitting by space and i also have spaces between [ ]

Comment: View the actual source of the page instead. `<` would cause the browser to start rendering as html, you would need to walk over the array with htmlentities if you want to display it, a pre tag wont help you. Also your be better off using [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

Comment: `$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file);` Would you try this?

Comment: What exactly is the data in the file? I would look at parsing it into an array first THEN sorting the array.

Comment: $lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $file); is also working so no problem with the .txt file, the problem is with the array format as I'm unable to get it into the format i need so i can add it into my database, so i assume i need to remove from lines < and > and to use preg_split with regex to split the content

Comment: Where is `$row` set? You need to show an example of an actual line, as `info` is not it, plus splitting by a space restricts you to single words so any answer will most likely be wrong.

Comment: @Hayden the data is from some tests i'm doing over some ips i own

Comment: @sasha Oh, okay. So, you're parsing a log file?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone there is no $row i've wrote it without doing a copy paste and i was thinking at a row variable instead of $line variable, i've edited the foreach code

Comment: @Hayden - exactly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$lines = file('data.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($lines as $line) {
    preg_match('#<(\w+)\s(\w+)\s(.+)\s\[(.+)\]\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+)>#', $line, $match);

    $info[] = [
        'info1' => $match[1],
        'info2' => $match[2],
        'time' => $match[3],
        'info' => $match[4],
        'ip' => $match[5],
    ];
}

print_r($info);
```

Will most likely not work on your real data, but I've asked for an example line but seems ignored.

https://3v4l.org/62UaD

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [info1] => info1
            [info2] => info2
            [time] => 0.10s
            [info] => info: info
            [ip] => 10.10.10.10:80
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [info1] => info1
            [info2] => info2
            [time] => 0.10s
            [info] => info: info, info
            [ip] => 10.10.10.10:80
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [info1] => info1
            [info2] => info2
            [time] => 0.10s
            [info] => info:80, info:25
            [ip] => 10.10.10.10:80
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [info1] => info1
            [info2] => info2
            [time] => 0.10s
            [info] => info: info, info, info:80, info:25
            [ip] => 10.10.10.10:80
        )

)
```

Comment: Its working very good, thank you very much for the explanation you've done by writing the preg_match() regex